# Error in set methods for object

Tags: java, object, getter-setter

Not quite sure why, but eclipse is putting an error on my setter methods that reads "Syntax error, insert "...VariableDeclaratoid" to complete FormalParamaterList."

Here's my code:

```
public class Student {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    Student() {

    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setID(i) {
        this.id = i;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(n) {
        this.name = n;
    }

    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("The student's name is: " + this.name);
        System.out.println("The student's ID is: " + this.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did not give your parameter `i` and `n` their types. See below

```
public void setID(int i) {
   this.id = i;
}



public void setName(String n) {
  this.name = n;
}
```